# PHP - How to check if current day/time is between two weekdays including time (from - to)

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to check if current date and time is between two weekdays which include time (from and to). There can be multiple records in the db and week days are stored via PHP date('N') where 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday) as well as hour - minute is stored via time.

For instance, a stored rule can be the following:
week_day_from : 5 (Friday)
week_hour_from : 16:00:00
week_day_to : 7 (Sunday)
week_hour_to : 18:00:00

or even
week_day_from : 7 (Sunday)
week_hour_from : 10:00:00
week_day_to : 2 (Tuesday)
week_hour_to : 12:00:00

How can I determine if current day/time applies in one of the rules? The main idea is to hide some results if one of the rule applies (i.e. do not show this meal after friday 16:00 and before Sunday 18:00)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The function getdate will give you more exact information. The function getDate() will return an array containing information about the weekday and time. By having the interval,you can determine if applies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes strtotime applies for current date/time but how can I apply this for every given rule which is not a specific date (i.e. every friday or every monday)?

Comment: I agree,then getdate will give you more exact information. The function getDate() will return an array containing information about the weekday and time.

Comment: Using getDate, you know what day it is today, number of second since 1970,and what weekday it is now. Then you can calculate using number of seconds if it within the range you mention above.

Comment: My problem was to define range, current day - weekday and seconds from 1970 for today is not a problem. The trick was to get weekday range (from - to) from db and apply according to current day/date. My pseudo dates approach is working fine till now, I used strtotime since I was pretty familiar with it. I will try getDate approach and report back. Thank you Skywalker

Answer (score 0):

found something....

had to create pseudo dates in order to use strtotime and compare with current date time. Pseudo dates are created via conditions as shown below which are commented to describe my logic.

I would much better prefer a MySQL query based solution rather than fetching all rules and compare but I can not find a way. I would be gratefull if you check my code and tell me what you think. Flaw may be possible...

```
    $daynow = date("N"); //$daynow = 7;
    $datetimenow = date("d-m-Y G:i:s"); 

    if($row['week_day_from'] > $row['week_day_to'])
    {// case from saturday(6) to thursday(4)
        if($daynow == 7)
        {
        $check_from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("Sunday + ".$row['week_day_from']." Days - 1 week"));
        $check_to = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("Sunday + ".$row['week_day_to']." Days"));
        }
        else
        {
        $check_from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("Sunday + ".$row['week_day_from']." Days - 2 week"));
        $check_to = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("Sunday + ".$row['week_day_to']." Days - 1 week"));
        }
    }
    else
    {// case from thursday(4) to saturday(6)
        if($daynow == 7)
        {
        $check_from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("Sunday + ".$row['week_day_from']." Days"));
        $check_to = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("Sunday + ".$row['week_day_to']." Days"));
        }
        else
        {
        $check_from = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("Sunday + ".$row['week_day_from']." Days - 1 week"));
        $check_to = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("Sunday + ".$row['week_day_to']." Days - 1 week"));
        }
    }

    if
    (
        strtotime($datetimenow) >= strtotime($check_from." ".$row['week_hour_from'])
        AND 
        strtotime($datetimenow) <= strtotime($check_to." ".$row['week_hour_to'])
    )
    {
    //RULE APPLIES
    }
```